# Passing UISegmentedControl values between controllers…

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, delegates, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to pass values from a segmented controller in one view controller to another. I found another question about this, but i don't understand how to actually implement the delegate method. (original question: [Passing UISegmentedControl values from FlipSideViewController in an Utility application to the mainviewcontroller…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717321/passing-uisegmentedcontrol-values-from-flipsideviewcontroller-in-an-utility-appl) )

FlipsideViewController.h

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;
-(void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index;

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
            id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

        IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapType_;

    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *mapType_;

    @end
```

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <XXXX> {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *mapType;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index {
    if (index == 0) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    if (index == 1) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    if (index == 2) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
  }
```

How do I call the method in the MainViewController???

```
  -(void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index {
```

Very thankful for any answers. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your utility view controller needs a pointer to the delegate
so

```
@property(weak) id< FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

---

then in your utility view controller has a IBAction when the view changes and calls the delegate

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:[sender selectedSegment]];
}
```

Comment: I tried. The app crashes. -[FlipsideViewController valueChangedMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd43790
2012-11-09 02:35:19.874.... any other ideas?

Comment: you actually need that method then ^^ hook up the view in the xib to the right IBAction in the FlipsideView and then you can pass it on from there like shown above. I can even whip you a small sample app... give me an hour, gotta eat